# Whenever, i try writing the numeric data into my .txt file, it raises an error

Tags: python, file

I've tried direct string conversions and multiples methods, however, the error keeps on arising.

```
f.write("Original Price: " + str(original_price) + "/n")
#Where original price is an integer taken through an html source.
```

The error:
    f.write("Original Price: " + str(original_price))
      File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\encodings\cp1252.py", line 19, in 
     encode
        return codecs.charmap_encode(input,self.errors,encoding_table)[0]
    UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\u20b9' in 
    position 16: character maps to

Looking for a method to write this information into my file.

Comment: that char is rupee. the `\u20b9` is rupee. it cannot encode it using unicode i guess. And, also it is `\n` not `/n`.

Comment: Why is Python trying to write cp1252; how did you open the file in the first place?

Answer (score 1):

The `write` method expects a `bytes` object; you are trying to pass a `str` object. You need to encode it first. To write the UTF-8 encoding of the string, for example,

```
f.write("Original Price: {}\n".format(original_price).encode('utf-8'))
```

The value of `original_price` doesn't seem to be an actual number; it contains the symbol for the rupee, `₹`, for which there is no equivalent in the character encoding you are trying to use.

Comment: hey chepner, you tried encoding? Because `TypeError: write() argument must be str, not bytes` error is raised.

Comment: What's the type of the `f` object?

Comment: (Also, my Python 2 bias is showing, but whatever `f` is, it's trying to encode the string using CP-1252, which doesn't have the rupee sign.)

Comment: i am trying with python 3. maybe this is the reason of the difference.

Comment: @OzgurBagci Yeah, `open` can return an object that will do the encoding for you in Python 3. That's the right answer, unless the OP is getting `f` in some other way. (But the idea is right regardless; `f` is *something* that's trying to encode the string to a character set that can't handle ₹.)

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution I guess:

You should open file with encoding parameter:

```
with open('towrite.txt, 'w+', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    f.write('Original Price: ' + str(original_price) + '\n')
```

This should work.